# BouncyCastle problems: Multiple webapps in one tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, bouncycastle

we have an issue with the BouncyCastle security provider. We're using it in two different webapps, but they're deployed by one single tomcat. 
We register the BC-provider at position 1 in the java.security.Security-Class.

Both webapps find the correct SecurityProvider, but the first webapp, which has registered BC initially seems to have 'the ownership' of it.

The second webapp tries to load the keystore as the following code shows:

```
if (Security.getSecurityProvider("BC") == null){
   keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
}else{
   keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", Security.getSecurityProvider("BC"));
}   
keyStore.load(in, this.pin);
```

Then at `keyStore.load(in, this.pin);` the following exception occurs:

> java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: inappropriate parameter type: javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec
>       at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.java:839)
>       at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)

We have this issue since we're using java8/tomcat8 - java7/tomcat7 worked fine.
So our assumption is, that this is caused by a change in classloader-mechanism in tomcat 8. 
Deploying the webapp in seperated tomcats is not an option for us...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it an option for you to install the BC provider jar as an extension library (in $JRE/lib/ext)?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using

```
Provider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
```

instead of

```
Provider provider = Security.getSecurityProvider("BC");
```

You can move the instantiation to a static field to do it only once if needed. Ridiculously simple given how much time this issue has cost me, trying to load BC with the right classloader and for each new installation having to deal with it again.